# Passing string_view when returning string

Tags: c++, string, string-view

I've been reading up on the benefits of using `std::string_view`, and why it should be used in parameter lists. And I understand that returning a `string_view` is generally not recommended.

However, say I have a simple function that accepts a `string` adds a suffix. I can think of two methods:

```
std::string AddSuffix(std::string_view inputString)
{
    return std::string(inputString) + "!";
}
```

Or

```
std::string AddSuffix(std::string inputString)
{
    return inputString + "!";
}
```

If I have to make a copy of the `inputString` either way, is there any reason to use one over the other?

Comment: The second option is a bit more readable and is preferable, but it's oversimplified. Usually functions have more return points independent on parameter values like `return {};` and the first option is preferable. Voting to close as "opinion-based" question.

Comment: One advantage of the 1st method: it doesn't require to construct a `std::string` for `inputString`. A `string_view` can be constructed without copy e.g. from a zero-terminated string literal.

Comment: If we're counting copies/moves, passing `std::string` by value is probably better, especially if you then do `std::move(inputString) + "!"`. But in reality I wouldn't bother, and would use a `std::string_view` parameter for consistency with everything else, then `std::format` (or equivalent) to add `"!"`.

Comment: @wohlstad ...except the function body then constructs `std::string` from it anyway. :(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right of course. I was just refering to the interface design.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of both your variants is that they create 2 `std::string` objects, both of which need to allocate memory (in case that those strings are long enough not to fit into the SSO buffer). The cause here is that `operator+` returns (by value) a new `string` object.

If you want to save one allocation, you can modify the `std::string_view` case as follows:

```
std::string AddSuffix(std::string_view inputString)
{
  std::string temp;
  temp.reserve(inputString.size() + 1);
  temp = inputString;
  temp += "!";
  return temp;
}
```

In this case, only a single allocation is required when RVO is applied (all major implementations will apply it).

Live demo showing allocations: https://godbolt.org/z/44P37qhP3.

Comment: `temp += "!";` is worse than `temp.push_back('!');`

Comment: @phuclv Could you explain why?

Comment: because it requires `std::string::operator+=(char*)` or `std::string::append(char*)` to scan for the null-terminator in the string to append, then copy all characters until that point, and some bad implementations may even create a new std::string from that and append. OTOH `std::string::push_back(char)`, `operator+=(char)`  or `std::string::append(char)` simply increase the size if required then write a single char at the end